# The étale topos is coherent: does the scheme need to be quasicompact?

Tags: compactness, schemes, topos-theory, etale-cohomology, grothendieck-topologies

It is known that the little étale topos of a scheme $X$ is coherent, i.e. the Grothendieck topology of the étale site is generated by a basis of finite coverings. For example, Butz and Moerdijk say that in the introduction to *Representing topoi by topological groupoids*.

I am trying to prove why: if the scheme is quasicompact, every element of the Grothendieck pretopology on the étale site, namely a covering of $X$ made by étale schemes, is an open cover, hence admits a finite subcovering.

But in general? Why is the theorem true if $X$ is not quasicompact?

Comment: I don't see how the claim is true if $X$ is not quasicompact. For instance, if $X$ is an infinite disjoint union, then there is covering of the terminal object of the little étale topos which doesn't have a finite subcovering. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was my point too. But I think I have found something that avoids this problem: see the first comment to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145821/interaction-petit-topos-gros-topos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!
SGA 4, VIII, explains that the étale topos is equivalent to the topos of sheaves on a smaller site, namely the one obtained as the full subcategory of affine finitely presented étale schemes over $X$.
Now affine implies quasicompact, so every covering has a finite subcovering.